# Select all data from monday to friday or select all data from weekdays

Tags: mysql

I was wondering what MySQL query to use to get all the data from Monday to Friday.
[image: Heres' a screenshot of my table]

By the way, the table name is logs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `WEEKDAY(date)` function, MONDAY is zero.

```
 SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE WEEKDAY(dateColumn) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
```

edit: according to the OP's data the date column might not be of type `datetime` so we can use the other fields like `day`,`month`, and `year` so use this query

```
SELECT * FROM logs
WHERE WEEKDAY(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4;
```

edit: OP wants to grab data only for current week, so use this query

```
SELECT * FROM logs
WHERE WEEKDAY(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
  AND WEEK(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day)) = WEEK(now());
```

Comment: I actually tried your query but it returned an empty result? Is it really the date column on the WEEKDAY function?

Comment: it should work. Can you try putting your dataset into sqlFiddle.com? Is your date column of type datetime? or is it varchar?

Comment: i edited my answer just in case you don't have your `date` column of type `datetime`, so we use the other columns `year`,`month`,`day` concat them together to create a valid date string

Comment: I tried the edited query but it retrieves all the data even if I add new entries for a different week, like 2014-01-06(monday of next week) and 2014-01-07(tuesday of next week), is it possible to retrieve the data within a week from monday to friday of the current week? what I want is actually to retrieve all the data within the current week from monday to friday..

Comment: just edited my answer again to get what you want current week monday to friday

Comment: is it also possible to query to get data last week?